# Arguments to an object's parent's function

Tags: python

In the "Dog" class, if I initialize as

```
self.print_func = print_func
```

shown below

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self, name, print_func):
        self.name = name
        self.print_func = print_func

class Dog(Pet):

    def __init__(self, name, print_func):
        Pet.name = name
        self.print_func = print_func


    def print_name(self):
        self.print_func(self.name)

def print_string(str):
print str
```

when I do

```
j.print_name()
```

everything is fine.

But if I initialize Dog class as

```
Pet.print_func = print_fun
```

i.e.,

```
class Dog(Pet):

        def __init__(self, name, print_func):
            Pet.name = name
            Pet.print_func = print_func


        def print_name(self):
            self.print_func(self.name)
```

when I do

```
j.print_name()
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: print_string() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

So why does calling self.print_func in the second case pass the "self" argument but not in the first case?

Answer (score 3):

It is because in the case of `self`, you're creating so called unbound function and in the second case, bound function. Bound function effectively translates to `Dog.print_func(self, self.name)`.

Bound methods are a bit special in a sense that they always require the self argument while functions don't. They also don't exist in the instances `__dict__` - which is exactly what happens: you're not assigning it to `self.__dict__`, but to `Pet.__dict__`, therefore `self` by Python implicitly.

In other words, setting `Pet.print_func` creates a method, while `self.print_func` creates a function.

Reason for this is the fact, that you're not calling `Pet` constructor - `Pet.print_func` modifies the parents list of methods. Small modification makes this more clear:

```
    class Dog(Pet):

    def __init__(self, name, print_func):
        Pet.name = name
        super(Dog, self).print_func = print_func
```

Output

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'print_func'
```

The attribute (or method) doesn't even exist! But, if the constructor is called...

```
class Dog(Pet):

    def __init__(self, name, print_func):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, print_func)
```

You are again assigning to a function. Output (given name='test'):

```
test
```

Exploring further, the behavior is becoming a bit more predictive. It can be summarized like this: if you add an attribute to a class, it is treated as a method. Adding an attribute to an instance leaves it as a function (or local attribute). Further example

```
class Dog(Pet):

    def __init__(self, name, print_func):
        Pet.name = name
        super(Dog, self).__dict__['print_func'] = print_func
```

Output (given name='test')

```
test
```

hopefully explains it well enough.